# Facebook Page Tab Not Receiving `page` Parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

I have a Facebook application that is meant to function in a *Page Tab*. However, when I load the tab, it seems to act more like a Canvas Page. That is to say, **I'm not being sent the `page` parameter in the `signed_request` sent to the page**.

When access the tab, http://facebook.com/page/app_APP_ID, and print all the the data in the `signed_request` I get:

```
[algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
[code] => BASE 64 Encoded Jumble
[issued_at] => 1334257763
[user_id] => 1073670219
```

However, I do not receive a `page` parameter like the [Facebook Docs say I should](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#integrating).

*I need to know the Page's ID to display the content specific to that page. Is there any reason I am not receiving it?*

Comment: I never figured it out. I think I gave up and made a new app.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did post a question regarding this and got some answers. You can check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308762/facebook-page-tab-app-signed-request-app-data-missing/24313156#24313156