# Facebook Page Tab App signed_request app_data missing

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm developing a Facebook **Page Tab** App - using Javascript SDK - which, on load, should show the contents of the signed_request posted by Facebook to my App. This signed_request should contain the "app_data" parameter, which is passed in the URL, like this:

*http_*//www.facebook.com/pages/MyPage-Community/SOME_ID?sk=MY_APP_ID&app_data=this_is_my_data

The link:

- MyPage-Community is a temporary Fan Page, which **is published**
- SOME_ID is, I guess, the page ID
- MY_APP_ID contains the app ID given by Facebook
- app_data=this_is_my_data (what I need)

Notes:

- The app itself is NOT in Development mode, so it's **publicly available**
- I'm using **localhost** to test the app
- I've tested with the developer account AND with a real regular account (set as App Tester, thus authorized)

Now, in the app code (javascript), I'm calling *FB.getLoginStatus(...)*, which gives me the authResponse object that contains, among other stuff, the *signedRequest* property - this one, when decoded, shows me these key/value pairs:

[algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256

[code] => SOME_CODED_STRING

[issued_at] => 1403183583

[user_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (my user id)

As you can see, the *app_data* property is not present as it was supposed to - as *page* should too, but I don't really need that one. Any ideas why this is happening? Can't find an answer anywhere. Could it be because I'm using localhost? Everything else seems to be working (although I do get an error when I try to "like" the page from within the app).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing the signed request which is POST'ed to your app and the `signedRequest` parameter of the response to the JS SDK's `getLoginStatus` method - they're not the same thing but are named similarly because they have a similar purpose

The JS SDK returns values more or less equivalent to what you receive on a Facebook canvas app, but it's not the same source of data or delivery mechanism, and won't have the same fields

To read the actual signed request with the `page` and `app_data`, you need to do it server side - instructions for which are here: `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games#checklogin` (It applies to page tab apps as well as canvas app)

Comment: Hmmm...I did spend some time trying to do this and going through the Facebook docs and some other sources and I ended up thinking signed_request and signedRequest would give me the same data. So, are you sure about this? If so, I will change my app to use server-side scripting (PHP) as the starting point, I guess. But, if possible, I would like to avoid that as I'm developing the app using AngularJS. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as correct because from what I can see it does address my question correctly. By the way: I just changed my index.html to index.php and added the necessary PHP code to get the signed_request and assign the app_data value to a javascript variable. I also changed the app settings (Tab Page URL) to reflect this change and all the AngularJS stuff seems to be working just fine, so now I can use the app_data variable to show specific content to the user in my Page Tab app. Thanks again!

Comment: how did you get the signed_request parameter in php, i am using codeigniter and in $_REQUEST i cannot find signed_request

Comment: Is this a new app you're using? new apps aren't told if the user likes the page, and older apps only retain this functionality until November